# Sinch Voip Calling not working mobile data

Tags: android, video, voip, sinch

I am working with sinch voip android sdk, when i connect the call over the mobile data then call gets connected but in between disable the mobile data and connect again call remains in freeze mode, and when i perform the same thing over the wifi the call gets connected, no freeze mode. My question is how can i connect the call again over the mobile data when i disable and enable the mobile data again.

Comment: give a try over quickblox

Comment: @MyMasterPeice  i am asking the solution, not to change to the sdk, sinch is quite better over the quickblox thats for sure.

Comment: Hi, Chris at sinch here, I will ask the team to look in to this. Could you by any chance send over a logcat to us at support@sinch.com